# Java HttpURLConnection is returning the same HTML despita using different links

Tags: java

My use-case requires reading a bunch of different URL s HTML-code, and all links come from the same website. I was passing 2 different URL s through my function, but i was only getting the results from the first time i passed the function  if i said `function("hello.html/hello")` and after that `function("hello.html/goodbye")` both functions would return the same exact HTML code. What could this be?

Comment: What is the website and the two pages you try exactly ? For some websites, the html content can be the same between the pages because there is javascript or other that update the content of the page, the html does not necessary change.

Comment: Its nasdaq.com, and it is not Javascript that updates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following display in the console two different html content:

```
package test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(function("https://www.nasdaq.com/fr/symbol/ndaq/real-time"));
        System.out.println(function("https://www.nasdaq.com/fr/symbol/ndaq/stock-chart"));
    }

    public static String function(String pURL) throws IOException {
        URL lURL = new URL(pURL);
        BufferedReader lIn = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(lURL.openStream()));

        String lInputLine;
        StringBuilder lBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((lInputLine = lIn.readLine()) != null)
            lBuilder.append(lInputLine);
        lIn.close();
        return lBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```